# Reading multiple ERA5 netcdf files

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray, era5

I have a collection of ERA5 netcdf files that contain hourly data for air temperature that span over approximately 40 years in the tropical East Pacific. In jupyter notebook, I want to run a bandpass filter on the merged dataset but I keep running into initial errors concerning memory allocation. I read the files using `xarray.open_mfdataset(list_of_files)`, but when I try to load the dataset I get the error:

```py
Unable to allocate X GiB for an array with shape (d1, d2, d3, d4) and data type float32
```

Are there work around solutions or best practices to manipulating large datasets like this in jupyter?

The full code for the bandpass filter is:
I've been wanting to apply a band pass filter to a large domain over the East Pacific over about 40 years of data from ERA5. The code goes as follows:

```py
# Grab dataset 
var = 't'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, 'era5_' + var + '_daily.nc'))
files.sort() 

# Read files into a dask array 
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(files)

# Limit study region 
lon_min = -140 
lon_max = -80 
lat_min = -10 
lat_max = 10 

ds = ds.sel(latitude = slice(lat_max, lat_min), longitude = slice(lon_min, lon_max))

# Now, load the data from the original dask array
da_T = ds.T.load() 

# High pass filter (remove singal on the seasonal and longer timescales)
import xrft
freq_threshold = (1/90) * (1/24) * (1/3600) # 90-day frequency threshold 

def high_pass_filter(da, dim, thres): 
    ft = xrft.fft(da, dim=dim, true_phase=True, true_amplitude=True)
    ft_new = ft.where(ft.freq_time > thres, other = 0)
    ft.close() 
    da_new = xrft.ifft(ft_new, dim = 'freq_time', true_phase=True, true_amplitude=True)
    da_new = da_new + np.tile(da.mean('time'), (da_T.time.shape[0],1,1,1))
    ft_new.close() 
    return da_new.real

da_new = high_pass_filter(da_T, 'time', freq_threshold)

# Save filtered dataset 
da_new.real.to_netcdf(os.path.join(outdir, 'era5_T.nc'))
```

Comment: If your data is too large to fit into memory, you’re not going to be able to load it. By using open_mfdataset you’re already working with a dask array. Check out the xarray docs on [parallel computing with dask](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.06.0/user-guide/dask.html) for a start. But we can’t give more guidance without seeing your code and knowing more about your workflow and where you’re stuck.

Comment: I've added my code to the original post. Where I'm stuck particularly is how to apply the actual bandpass on the large dataset if it isn't possible to read in the data. Can this be resolved with just segmenting the data spatially?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```py
# Now, load the data from the original dask array
da_T = ds.T.load()
```

you are loading all the data in the `"T"` variable of your dataset into memory all at once. Presumably the size of this variable is larger than the amount of RAM available on your system.

You also have another problem with this line: `da.load()` loads in-place and returns the modified object. So `ds.T.load()` alone would have been sufficient. You could also have done `da_T = ds.T.compute()` instead.

You could try using dask to perform your analysis chunk-by-chunk. You want to ensure that your `ds` object contains chunked dask array objects **before you load/compute it**.

You then want to specify your analysis using xarray methods / the xrft package as you are doing, but only call `.compute()` at the end. This should do your analysis in a chunk-by-chunk manner.

I suggest reading about how to use dask + xarray together though in order to get this to run smoothly.